# How to set Request Headers before it being loaded in an iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, http-headers

I need to download a file which '**Content-Disposition**' header being set to "`attachment`" by server. I am using  `jQuery.ajax` for `GET` and on success setting  hidden `iframe` `src` to `url`, which gives me a pop-up for file download. And its working fine in all browsers.
Now I want to change a custom request headers to encrypt file before GET & download. I used  `jQuery.ajax` pre-request callback function `beforeSend` for it.

I am able to GET my encrypted file which I can observe in firebug but my `iframe` still shows non encrypted file for download. After inspecting I can say that `iframe` requesting a new GET .

**Code**

```
$.ajax({
url: "/tutorial.text",
beforeSend: function(xhr) {  xhr.setRequestHeader("PASSWORD_HEADER", userPwd);  },
success: function() {   $("#Hidden_iframe").attr("src", this.url);  }                                   
});
```

And this is working good on Internet explorer. How can i force iframe to use the available resource rather than requesting new GET.
Or How can I **setRequestHeader** in iframe or do I really need a `jQuery.Ajax` for this task is there any best way to download the Content-Disposition header being set to attachment files directly from server.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?  I am trying to do something similar...  Download a file through an ajax call, but the download requires authentication and it is cross domain....

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't uses iframe or form. It uses XHR with custom header on a resource that supports CORS (just random svg from the internet for this example). The key differences in this approach is `xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';` and a link with `blob` href and `download` attributes:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3p7qg1tn/1/)

```js
// some initial data
var url = '//enable-cors.org/img/cloud-download.svg';
var password = '123456';

// download url into arrayBuffer
function download (url, password, cb) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    // xhr.setRequestHeader('PASSWORD_HEADER', password);
    xhr.onload = function () {
        cb(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.send(null);
}

// receive binary content of url
// create blob link and click on it
download(url, password, function (arrayBuffer) {
  var file = new File([arrayBuffer], 'some filename');
  var a = document.createElement('A');
  a.setAttribute('href', window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
  a.setAttribute('download', 'file-name-of-download.ext');
  // in firefox `a.click()` works only if `a` element is in DOM, so...
  document.documentElement.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  console.log('done');
});
```

Tested in Chrome57 and FF54.